# CSS conflict with JavaScript function increase decrease font size.

Tags: javascript, css

I am using this function :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("umar");  
// Reset Font Size
  var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    $(".reset").click(function(){
    $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
  });
  // Increase Font Size
  $(".in").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
  // Decrease Font Size
  $(".de").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*0.8;
    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

for increasing and decreasing font size but its conflicts with CSS when I remove this line. This function works :

```
 <link id="default-css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var fontSizeCookie = getCookie('font_size');
    if (typeof fontSizeCookie !== 'undefined' && fontSizeCookie != null) {
        jQuery('html').css('font-size', fontSizeCookie+'px');
    }

    // Reset Font Size
    var originalFontSize = 10;
    jQuery(".resetFont").click(function(){
        jQuery('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
        createCookie('font_size', originalFontSize, 365);
    });
    // Increase Font Size
    jQuery(".increaseFont").click(function(){
        var currentFontSize = jQuery('html').css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
        var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
        jQuery('html').css('fontSize', newFontSize+'px');
        createCookie('font_size', newFontSize, 365);
        return false;
    });
    // Decrease Font Size
    jQuery(".decreaseFont").click(function(){
        var currentFontSize = jQuery('html').css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
        var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*0.8;
        jQuery('html').css('fontSize', newFontSize);
        createCookie('font_size', newFontSize, 365);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this below line in `style.css`

```
.newFontSize { font-size: 10px !important; }
```

And replace JavaScript code with this one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("umar");  
// Reset Font Size
  var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    $(".reset").click(function(){
    $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
  });
  // Increase Font Size
  $(".in").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
    $('html').addClass('newFontSize');
    $(".newFontSize ").css('font-size', newFontSize);        
    return false;
  });
  // Decrease Font Size
  $(".de").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*0.8;
    $('html').addClass('newFontSize');
    $(".newFontSize ").css('font-size', newFontSize); 
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```